# Applicative vs monadic style for simple IO example

Tags: haskell, monads, applicative

Here's two really simple functions `f` and `g`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

module Test where

import Control.Applicative

f :: IO ()
f = do
    y <- (<*>) (pure (show . (*10))) (read <$> readFile "data")
    writeFile "out" y

g :: IO ()
g = do
    y <- (readFile "data" >>= return . show . (*10) . read)
    writeFile "out" y
```

The file read and `*10` in `f`is written in the applicative style with `pure` and `(<*>)`. The file read and `*10` in `g` is written in the monadic style, with `>>=`. (I have deliberately avoided using `liftM` in `g` to emphasize the question below).

What is the semantic difference between `f` and `g`? Or in this case, is it just a stylistic choice?

Comment: The monadic style looks a lot more readable to me at least :)

Comment: You could write `(<*>) (pure (show . (*10))) (read <$> readFile "data")` as `show . (*10) . read <$> readFile "data"`

Comment: The `<-` and the `return` in `g` basically cancel each other out, `do { y <- readFile "data"; writeFile "out" (show . (*10) . read $ y) }` would be shorter (and arguably less contrived).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`show . (*10) . read` is a "non-monadic" function - by which I mean, it does not do anything in the IO monad, as you can see from its type.

`>>= return .` can be shortened to

```
`liftM`
```

But

```
`liftM`
```

should always be equivalent to

```
`fmap`
```

`fmap` neither needs the monad typeclass nor the applicative typeclass, it merely needs the functor typeclass.

Now turning our attention to the applicative version, this:

```
(<*>) (pure ...
```

is equivalent to `<$>`, which is just `fmap`.

So in both cases we are "really" just working with a functor operation, inbetween reading and writing, and although you have combined the functions in a slightly different way (we'd need to apply one or more "laws" to translate the two versions into each other), the semantics are - or should be - identical. Certainly they are with the IO monad, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the choice is purely stylistic, but both can be tidied up to be more idiomatic:

The applicative functions are best written as operators, and pointfree:

```
f :: IO ()
f = show . (*10) . read <$> readFile "data" >>= writeFile "out"
```

In monadic style, it looks neater if you go more wholeheartedly not pointfree, avoiding operators:

```
g :: IO ()
g = do 
    y <- readFile "data" 
    let x = show . (*10) . read $ y
    writeFile "out" x
```